# Terminating Autoscaling instances in Pending:Wait state (w/ Terraform)

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am using Terraform to manage EC2 Autoscaling Groups with a startup lifecycle hook. I've run into an issue with autoscaling groups where scale in (when reducing the desired instance count) will stop Healthy instances but not instances in the Pending:Wait state. This is especially painful when Terraform attempts to stop an autoscaling group that didn't start correctly. It will have no healthy instances, and autoscaling will be constantly creating new instances that get stuck in the Pending:Wait state. Terraform will set the desired instance count to 0, but then get stuck waiting until the last Pending:Wait instances time out.

Ideally I want a way to tell EC2 Autoscaling that it can terminate Pending:Wait instances when scaling in. Alternatively, a way to configure Terraform to reduce the timeout on my lifecycle hook when destroying the autoscaling group, even if tainted, would be valuable.